# Start IE 10 in IE7 and IE8 mode with batch commands

Tags: batch-file, tabs, command, standards, internet-explorer-10

Is it possible to start a **.html** page with **IE10** from the batch command open two tabs, each one in **IE7** and **IE8** mode, respectively? Where can I find what argument does IE accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the page hasn't been updated since Jan' 2011, Microsoft give the following command line options in Internet Explorer and unfortunately none for starting in IE7 or IE8 modes:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh826025.aspx

This currently lists the following:

```
iexplore.exe [ [ -embedding ] 
           [ -extoff ] 
           [ -framemerging ] 
           [ -k ] 
           [ -noframemerging ]
           [ -nohangrecovery ]
           [ -private ] ]
         [ URL ]
```

You sound like you're familiar with using the developer tools in IE10 which can emulate earlier versions but just in case someone is browsing this who doesn't, use commands: (F12, Ctr+8, Document Mode->X, where X is the version you want to emulate).